# Cannot change md-select value programmatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Im trying to change the item of md-select programmatically and tried using `ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}"` but this code won't work. Did i missed something so simple?

You can take a look at this **[DEMO](https://codepen.io/badcoder28/pen/rmWLWE)**

Answer (score 0):

The `md-select` element does not have an attribute for `ng-model-options` since it's not stated in the [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.1/api/directive/mdSelect).

Anyways, it looks like you have to instead of `track by data`, use `track by $index`.

```html
<md-select ng-model="selectedAnimal">
    <md-option 
        ng-value="item"
        ng-repeat="item in data track by $index">
        {{item.animal}}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

[Updated Codepen](https://codepen.io/Chan4077/pen/BRQQXd)

Comment: hi there, It is stated in the docs you can see it on Selects and object equality section of the md-select directive. your code doesnt seems to work when i click the button still nothing happened.